# vertical navigation submenu should overlap div container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this sidepanel vertical navigation wherein sub-menus are displayed when hovered on a menu. My problem is that the sub-menus and children of the sub-menus are not being showing due to the div container.

Since the div container [side-panel-links] has a width of 240px, it is cutting it off. If you extend the width of the div container, then you'll see the sub-menus being displayed.

How could I possibly let the sub-menus overlap the div container to show these submenus?

Here's the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/xkBZE/1/

Here's a snippet of the HTML code :

```
    <div class="side-panel-links left">
    <div class="side-panel-links-scroll">
        <div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">
            <ul id="side-panel-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Test 1</a>
                    <ul class="side-panel-list-child"></ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Test 2</a>
                    <ul class="side-panel-list-child">
                        <li>Test 2-1
                            <ul class="side-panel-list-child">
                                <li>Test 2-1-1
                                    <ul class="side-panel-list-child">
                                        <li>Test 2-1-1-1
                                            <ul class="side-panel-list-child"></ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>Test 2-1-2
                                    <ul class="side-panel-list-child"></ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Test 2-2
                            <ul class="side-panel-list-child">
                                <li>Test 2-2-1
                                    <ul class="side-panel-list-child"></ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>Test 2-3
                            <ul class="side-panel-list-child">
                                <li>Test 2-3-1
                                    <ul class="side-panel-list-child">
                                        <li>Test 2-3-1-1
                                            <ul class="side-panel-list-child"></ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Test 3</a>
                    <ul class="side-panel-list-child"></ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Test 4</a>
                    <ul class="side-panel-list-child"></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not be using the same id for everything, thats what classes are for.
To show something outside of the box i would use `position: absolute;z-index:100;`on that element, in this case the `<ul>` nested in the `<li>`.

Hope this helps

I just couldn't wrap my head around your css so
i changed it to this:

--> **updated css**

```
.side-panel-links{
width: 240px;
background-color: #272727;
padding-top: 25px;
font: normal 11px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
}
.jqueryslidemenu ul li ul{
left: 0;
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
}
#side-panel-list{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#side-panel-list li {
border-top: 1px solid #353535;
border-bottom: 1px solid #191919;
padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
margin: 0;
}
#side-panel-list li ul{
position: absolute;
left: 300px;
display: list-item;
}
#side-panel-list li a {
color: #EEE;
margin: 0 50px 0 0;
width: 161px;
display: list-item;
color: white;
padding: 8px 8px;
border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
text-decoration: none;
}
#side-panel-list li ul li{
padding: 5px;
display: block;
background-color: red;
}
#side-panel-list li a:link,
#side-panel-list li a:visited {
color: white;
}
#side-panel-list li a:hover{
background: black;
color: #426BA4;
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

altough this works it still needs a bit more styling to get the same look as you did before.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Graviton!

Yes, sorry for the ID thing. I was just copy-pasting it and didn't notice that part. Anyway, I already did try making it position absolute with a high value for z-index (i even set it to 9999 just to make sure) but it didn't work.

Here's an updated demo using the position absolute and z-index.

[http://jsfiddle.net/xkBZE/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/xkBZE/5/)

Comment: Hi Graviton, thanks for this!

I got to apply your code. Though I'm not sure if I'm doing it right because the last <li> only shows up. Here's the output : [http://jsfiddle.net/GHZ9k/](http://jsfiddle.net/GHZ9k/)

Comment: i updated the css, now it shows all of the items but it does not yet show up next to the element. But i'm afraid i don't have any more time to look at it right now. Good luck perfecting it.